# The "out" keyword of C# 8 doesn't pass "System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis" rules?

Tags: c#, out, c#-8.0, nullable-reference-types

I'm converting some code from C#5 to C#8, enabling nullable-check in compilation ruleset,

```
<Nullable>enable</Nullable>
```

then I met a problem like this:

```
class Person
{
    public int MI { get; set; } = 3;
}
class UseWeakReference
{
    public static void Main(string [] args)
    {
        Person person = new Person();
        WeakReference<Person> wr = new WeakReference<Person>(person);

        wr.TryGetTarget(out Person p1); // doesn't compile
        Console.WriteLine(p1);
    }
}
```

The compilation error is:

```
CS8600: Converting null literal or possible null value to non-nullable type.
```

What's the real cause of this compiling error, and how to fix it?

Comment: wr.TryGetValue(out p1);

Comment: @HirasawaYui: since C#7 is has been possible to declare out variables in the parameters of a method : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/whats-new/csharp-7#out-variables

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can allow the `out` parameter to be a possible null reference and compare it with `null` value after method call

```cs
wr.TryGetTarget(out Person? p1);
if (p1 != null)
    Console.WriteLine(p1);
```

Or simply check the return result of `TryGetTarget` method: when it's `true`, the `p1` can't be `null`

```cs
var result = wr.TryGetTarget(out Person? p1);
if (result)
    Console.WriteLine(p1);
```

The reason of compiler warning is that [`TryGetTarget`](https://source.dot.net/#System.Private.CoreLib/WeakReference.T.cs,655561bce79c86cd) implemented like that

```cs
public bool TryGetTarget([MaybeNullWhen(false), NotNullWhen(true)] out T target)
{
    // Call the worker method that has more performant but less user friendly signature.
    T o = this.Target;
    target = o!;
    return o != null;
}
```

The nullability of `out` parameter determined based on return value, according to `[MaybeNullWhen(false), NotNullWhen(true)]` attributes, and can't be determined at compile time, only at runtime.

When you assign it to non-nullable reference, compiler warns you about possible problems. Checking the return result or use `Person?` seems to be a proper solution here

Answer (score 1):

There's no guarantee that `p1` won't be null when the method returns. However, `TryGetValue` is annotated to say that if it returns `true` then the out parameter won't be `null`, so write your code as:

```
if(wr.TryGetTarget(out var p1))
{
    Console.WriteLine(p1);
}
```

`p1` will have type `Person?` but the compiler will do flow analysis to show that as `TryGetTarget` returned `true` it knows that `p1` is not `null` and can be treated as a `Person`.